# commandlink in JSF not generating the intended HTML tag (nothing warp html included)

Tags: jsf

I have This Line of code in xhtml :

```
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-4 text-center">
    <h:commandLink action="#{pwaService.payment(3)}">
        <div class="box-info-activity shadow clickable"
             style="height: 104px!important;width: 104px!important;">
            <a class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x  mt-2"></a>
                <p class="mt-3">#{pwaService.getPrice(3)} ريال</p>
      <h:outputText styleClass="mt-1" value="یک ساله"/>
           <p class="mt-3">خرید</p>
       </div>
        <f:ajax/>
   </h:commandLink>
   </div>
 </div>
```

As I aspect This code shows up in render jsf like blowe :

```
<div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-4 text-center">
<a id="j_idt13" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,0);return false">
                            <div class="box-info-activity shadow clickable" style="height: 104px!important;width: 104px!important;"><a id="j_idt13" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,0);return false">
                                </a><a class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x  mt-2"></a>
                                <p class="mt-3">
                                    ۵۰۰۰۰۰۰ ريال
                                </p><span class="mt-1">یک ساله</span>

                                <p class="mt-3">خرید</p>
                            </div>
</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But the h:command shows up like this :

```
<div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-4 text-center"><a id="j_idt13" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,0);return false">
                            </a><div class="box-info-activity shadow clickable" style="height: 104px!important;width: 104px!important;"><a id="j_idt13" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,0);return false">
                                </a><a class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x  mt-2"></a>
                                <p class="mt-3">
                                    ۵۰۰۰۰۰۰ ريال
                                </p><span class="mt-1">یک ساله</span>

                                <p class="mt-3">خرید</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How can I warp the content of h:commandlink into it?

The Head of xhtml file for jsf  :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
>
```

In this case I need create a div that can users click on it with all content inside of it, but the a tag shows up outside of div and not clickable by user.
**The problem is render jsf close a tag immediate after render and not with whole content in it.**

In easy way to say :

if I use <h:commandLink> and not close tag , after write some html content and close </h:commandLink> all html content need show up in render, but the render show up with  tag that close() after call.
Why is this happen? what can I do?

Comment: Where did you look? In the raw HTML source (right click, view page source) or via the element inspector in webbrowser's developer tools (F12, elements)? If the latter then that's indeed expected. See HTML spec. Is it causing problems for you at all? If so which exactly? This is in turn completely unrelated to JSF. It's in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You will have exactly the same problem when using a completely different MVC framework producing the exact same piece of HTML or even when using a static hardcoded HTML file.

Comment: From F12, Elements, Yes The code Rendered from jsf shows a tag open and close Immediately without any other html content and after close a tag , we see the html content. the other part of your comment I don't understand, it can be for my English or lack of knowledge about jsf. Thanks for replay @BalusC

Comment: That's the browser's interpretation of the retrieved HTML output. In order to see what exactly JSF has generated do a right click, *View page source*. You'll see that it's exactly as you intended. You would still have observed exactly the same browser behavior when you copy paste that HTML output into a static *.html file and then open it in the webbrowser without using JSF. So, in other words, the observed problem is **not** caused by JSF.